# Nodejs alpine Docker puppeteer won't start

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, puppeteer, node-modules

I tried ti dockerize my node app, but it won't work because of this puppeteer error, can you help me fixing this error? The Troubleshooting Site doesn't.
Thanks, regards Steep

Below is the error

```
node app.js
/usr/src/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:197
            reject(new Error([
                   ^
Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /usr/src/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-901912/chrome-linux/chrome ENOENT
TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md
    at onClose (/usr/src/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:197:20)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/src/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:189:85)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

And the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install --production --silent && mv node_modules ../
COPY . .
RUN chown -R node /usr/src/app
USER node
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Please post Dockerfile as well so we can diagnosticate the issue.

Comment: For sure, added it :)

Comment: Why are you moving `node_modules` 1 directory above?

Comment: That was automatically generated by Visual Studio Code